# wso2 server redeployment error "Faulty Carbon Applications."

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting an error whenever I tried to redeploy the app to the esb. I am trying to merge the 2 response from different api and then map and manipulate that response. I am also using the latest 5.0.0 BETA version both esb tooling and esb.

Here is the fault reason

> org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from
>   the file :
>   /Users/me/Downloads/wso2esb-5.0.0-BETA2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1468999438631movieapiApp_1.0.0.car/movieAPI_1.0.0/movieAPI-1.0.0.xml
>   : Failed. at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:213)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.synapse.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:131)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager.deployCarbonApp(ApplicationManager.java:263)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.CappAxis2Deployer.deploy(CappAxis2Deployer.java:72)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:93)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:138)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: API deployment from
>   the file :
>   /Users/me/Downloads/wso2esb-5.0.0-BETA2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1468999438631movieapiApp_1.0.0.car/movieAPI_1.0.0/movieAPI-1.0.0.xml
>   : Failed. at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:201)
>   ... 20 more Caused by:
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: API
>   deployment from the file :
>   /Users/me/Downloads/wso2esb-5.0.0-BETA2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/1468999438631movieapiApp_1.0.0.car/movieAPI_1.0.0/movieAPI-1.0.0.xml
>   : Failed. at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:474)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:71)
>   at
>   org.wso2.carbon.rest.api.ApiDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ApiDeployer.java:34)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.deploy(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:194)
>   ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Duplicate
>   resource definition by the name: movieapi at
>   org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.handleException(SynapseConfiguration.java:1627)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration.addAPI(SynapseConfiguration.java:414)
>   at
>   org.apache.synapse.deployers.APIDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(APIDeployer.java:59)
>   ... 22 more

and here's my api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/movieapi" name="movieapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/*">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="ROOT" scope="default">
                <root:movie xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
            </property>
            <log level="full"/>
            <clone continueParent="true" id="movie" sequential="true">
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address format="rest" uri="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt0918940?api_key=code&amp;append_to_response=casts,images%22"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <sequence>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint>
                                <address format="rest" uri="https://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&amp;i=tt0918940"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <aggregate id="movie">
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="ROOT" expression="//jsonObject" xmlns:dummy="http://org.dummy" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                    <respond/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

and this is from the terminal

```
[2016-07-20 15:36:48,890] ERROR - DataMapperMediator DataMapper mediator : mapping configuration is null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting in the terminal `DataMapperMediator DataMapper mediator : mapping configuration is null` is because the relevant registry resources are not deployed (more precisely, the configuration .dmc file). When you are deploying the capp, make sure that all the registry resources are included as well. Also when the capp deployment fails, can you check in the management console for any faulty services/APIs?

Comment: Where can I find that management console? I just followed this guide here https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Using+Data+Mapper+Mediator+in+WSO2+ESB and here's my movieapiApp pom.xml http://pastebin.com/6ZVHpawb and here's my file http://imgur.com/a/70WCN

Comment: Well I just started again from scratch and I finally uploaded the carbon.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error indicating Data mapper configurations null. So you have to add relevant configurations as you given in the proxy:

```
<datamapper config="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
```

For example: You indicated about **gov:datamapper/movieapiMapping.dmc**

This should be available in governance registry.Please deploy relevant configs in to ESB.

Comment: I think because the esb server is not sync with my esb tooling as you can see from my fault reason every time i tried to redeploy the app to esb

Comment: This will be helpful : https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS350/Deploying+and+Debugging and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxWz1qdSL9Q

Answer (score 0):

Open the pom.xml file inside your CompositeApplication. 
Edit it in the Design mode.
Under dependencies, you can see the artifacts which you can include. 
Tick the checkbox near your relevant Registry artifact. Save pom file.
Now redeploy the application to the server or Regenerate your car file